# JavaScript error in aptana

Tags: javascript, validation, aptana

Aptana is showing error at this line:

```
var myVar = myVar1 = myVar2;
```

although when I deploy this script it works fine in FF or IE.

**EDIT** : it is showing an error on the second `=` sign, it is expecting a; instead got `=` sign.

Comment: Editors sometimes do that. I use eclipse and it sometimes highlights code that is valid. Goes away after a bit though. Does this remain even after a few mins?

Comment: Is `myVar1` previously declared? Do you know that by `var a = b = 1;` you are just declaring the `a` variable? (`b` is implicitly created, not really "declared")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like an error coming from the JSLint JavaScript Validator. It's most likely complaining because myVar1 is not being declared with "var". You have a couple of options:

1. Under Preferences->Aptana->Validation you can select "JavaScript" and turn off JSLint JavaScript Validator. There is a Mozilla JavaScript Validator that isn't as strict.
2. Add a filter on that same pref page to effectively ignore that type of error. I think you only need a substring from the error message like "was not declared correctly", for example
3. You can define separate var declarations as below:

Samples:

```
// version 1
var myVar = myVar2,
    myVar1 = myVar2;
```

or

```
// version 2
var myVar = myVar2;
var myVar1 = myVar2;
```